# Mpeg TS: How works video/audio sync

Tags: synchronization, mpeg

I am trying multiple video to one stream(TS), and broadcast via DVBT.
Also, I found pcr is used for video/audio sync.
But, pcr is in only video stream.
Then, How works video / audio sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PCR is use to detect drift in playback speed retaliative to the broadcast encoder. The audio and video streams both have timestamps (in the PES header) for every frame that are synced to the PCR.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you explain more detail?

Comment: In what regard specifically?